# How to debug a Python script, to which items piped in?

Tags: python, debugging, pipe

On Windows 10 in a Command Prompt

C:\script> python ps1.py a11 a12 | python ps2.py a21 a22

works fine, ps1 creates items, which are processed by ps2.
Now I want to debug ps2.py (it became a big script). I tried many ways, all failed; I describe only one here.
I put breakpoint() at the beginning of the script and got the (Pdb) prompt and as many error messages as many items were in the pipe and a Traceback pointing to the line just after the breakpoint(). If I put the breakpoint() where the pipe is empty, I got only the Traceback. So the main question is, how to debug ps2.py, when the pipe holds items?

Answer (score 1):

Use pysnooper Python package. You can track every line
Import pysnooper
Refer :https://github.com/cool-RR/PySnooper

Comment: Thanks, Chanda, for the suggestion, I’ll use PySnooper when it is appropriate, but, as far as I see, it is not answer to my question. First, it is not a debugger, but a tracer; second, I don’t see how to trace code not in a function.